# Как вывести последнее поле из DBGrida?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Здравствуйте, форумчане, у меня следующий вопрос по Delphi. В DBGride есть колонка порядковый номер, и заполнена она 1, 2, 3... и т.д. И можно ли последнюю строку этой колонки вывести в lаbеl?

Comment: или как сделать, чтобы было нельзя повторять одно и тоже число в колонке?

Comment: Число записей, что-ли вывести? Тогда для этого не сам DBGrid нужен, а метод его набора данных (таблицы или запроса) *Table.RecordCount;

Comment: нет, вот например в DBGride последняя запись в колонке "порядковый номер" 45, вот мне в lable нужно вывести 45. 
если я добавлю следующую запись с номером 80, то он должен заменить 45 на 80 в lable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Последнюю строку столбца с порядковым номером можно вывести так:

```
procedure TForm1.ADOTable1AfterPost(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  ADOTable1.Last;
  Label1.Caption:=ADOTable1.Fields[5].AsString; // у Вас будет свой номер столбца
  ADOTable1.First; // в начало, можно не переходить, если не нужно
end;
```

Это обработчик набора данных OnAfterPost (т. е. выведет после сохранения).

Answer (score 0):

Делай вывод последней записи по Table.RecordCount, выводи то поле которое содержит твоё "45" FieldByName(заголовок_столбца).Value DBText'ом, ну или в label'ом.
IntToStr(Table1.RecNo) - так же можно узнать общее кол-во записей, отсюда и порядковый номер последней, для вывола его значений по полям. 
А я делал проще:

```
table1.Last;
label2:=Table1.FieldByName('Имя_поля_в_котором_значение').Value;
table1.First
```